# Can't access object property in Javascript, property key is from FileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm using FileReader in Javascript in order to create an Object that has the data. The file itself is a textfile, and the function is configured to make a property for that has all the data under a certain section of the file that starts with a bracketed word and splits by newline '\n', e.g.:

[chapter]

`data, data, data`

`data2, data2, data2`

becomes:

```
myObject['chapter'] = ['data, data, data', 'data2, data2, data2'];
```

but when I use the Chrome console (or use console.log) in order to access `myObject['chapter']` it returns undefined. Using the console to look at the properties, it shows that the object does have the properties, but with double quotes?

[screenshot looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYQLY.png)

messing around with the console further reveals that this "chapter" is different from all others. Examples:

```
myObject['chapter'] = 2
//this creates a new property 'chapter', while "chapter" also exists.
Object.keys(myObject)[0] == 'chapter';
//evaluates to false
```

edit: spelling

```
function drophandle(e) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let data = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        let yet = event.target.result.toString();
        let full_arr = yet.split('\n');
        let index = 'file-f'
        items[index] = [];

        for (let line of full_arr) {
            if (line.indexOf('[') != -1) {
                index = line.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").toLowerCase();
                items[index] = [];
                continue;
            };
            items[index].push(line);
        }
        console.log(items['general'])
        for (let t in items) {
            for (let y of items[t]) {
                append(y)
            }
        }
    }
    reader.readAsText(data, 'utf-8');
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please paste your code (minimal example that reproduces the issue). I doubt that it is a matter of simple/double-quotes. Could be you do not get the keys you expect from your file (e.g. '\n' could be in the key). Also could be that `console.log` is not synchronous in chrome and `myObject` has changed when chrome decides to log it.

Comment: Have you noticed: `Object.keys(MyObject)[0]` starts with a capital letter? ...

Comment: sorry that was a typo rather than a mistake. the code was supposed to be analogous to what I was coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject['chapter'] = 2
//this creates a new property 'chapter', while "chapter" also exists.
Object.keys(myObject)[0] == 'chapter';
```

is m , not M